# Can anyone help identify this "retro" muddyfox frame?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

My apologies I can't provide any further information, purchased from a flea market (primarily because I needed big horizontal dropouts) it has "DSP15t02" although that helps very little on Google. The obvious "Muddyfox" and "Dualpro" stickers on it (which are under the finish of the paint and don't seem after market jobs. None of the other parts came with it, they're a parts bin selection. [image: this bike]

Comment: The support piece between top tube and down tube is reminiscent of the Muddyfox Dual Slalom, but the horizontal drop outs look quite different (so do the chain stays)

Comment: Good shout. Having checked the Dual Slalom the only difference's I can see are the seat stays are tube rather than box and mine has removable rim brake bosses.  Those chain stays are comically large though.

Comment: Just confirming - it was not electric originally?  The rear trackends are quite unique on this kind of bike, may be key.

Comment: Are they 26"  wheels?  Is hard to get the scale of the bike.  It could be 24" compared ti tge franem or even 27.5" based on the rotors.

Comment: Definitely not electric originally, the frame (more specifically the rear drop outs) were ideal for lots of torque through the back axle. Many other frames bent. It's a 26" wheel, anything bigger won't fit and anything smaller missies the rim brakes (if fitted). I can measure various parts of needed. Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I've searched a lot and can't find anything that matches.  Muddyfox made a lot of bikes over time, so this is less of an answer and more of a dump of observations:

Points to note

- Overall the bike looks "thick" - the chainstays are chunky, as are the seatstays.
- Having trackends for rear dropouts is quite unusual on a MTB, but less unusual on a BMX.
- The frame reinforcing gussets behind the head tube are unusual for a MTB.
- The front suspension looks newer than mid 2000 because it lacks the stanchion boots which were common on earlier forks.
- Paint on forks looks identical to frame so its likely to be original, making the bike a 26" hardtail
  downtube

From a distance, it looks like a BMX, with a relatively low seatpost clamp.

I bet there's no brazeon mount for a front derailleur - and it may help to look closely for any paint marks where a bandon derailleur might have mounted.  If nothing found, I'd say this was a 1x setup from new.

At the rear, you have an electric motor now.  Was there any indication of a rear derailleur at any point ?  If not, this suggests the bike was a single speed OR it was fitted with an internally geared hub from new, both of which need trackends to set the chain/belt tension.

**UPSHOT** I think its a mid 2000 bigger kid's frame, designed to "evoke" the BMX, so possibly intended for teenage boys who have outgrown their 20" BMX.

It might even be called a 26" BMX in the right light.

Comment: The proportion of the frame is misleading, I'm 6'2" and it doesn't feel small, but the thick tubes make the bike look small. It's bizzare, I can't find any information on it. The forks are blind luck, cheap suntour jobs that I got from a carboot sale for £3.00 just happened to match the colour perfectly! Thank you all for your comments btw, this community is amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Not to worry everyone, it seems that I have a circa 2000 **Muddyfox BSX Dual Pro** whatever that means.

Turns out "a 26" BMX in the right light" is exactly correct! Many thanks.

Snapped it though, so never mind.